# select rows depending on an array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array which populated by a cookie. The length differ each time. The values that contains are ids taht I want to select from a database. I know that I can use something like below to retrieve multiple rows with specific ids:

`$query  = "SELECT game_id,thumb,title,rating,instructions FROM games WHERE game_id IN ('111','110')";`

My question is, how can I retrieve from the database the ids of the array `$favGames` ? I found in another question the following: `WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';` but it doesn't seems to works for me. What other options do I have?

Comment: Did you change $ids in the example to $favGames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT game_id,thumb,title,rating,instructions FROM games WHERE game_id IN ('" . implode("','", $favGames) ."')";
```

If you don't have the extra single quotes in the call to implode, your query would look like:

> SELECT
>   game_id,thumb,title,rating,instructions
>   FROM games WHERE game_id IN
>   ('111,110')

Notice the missing quotes? That's what's causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't $ids be $favGames in your second expression? And are all ids numeric? If they are not, then you need to add '' around the elements just like in your initial query